# How to get random key from firebase in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: example]

How can I get random key from Firebase realtime database that are stored in list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("inspirational");

reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
       String keys=datas.getKey();
      }
  }
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
      }
  });
```

First you need to go the dataSnapshot `inspirational`, then iterate inside of it and, this will give you the random keys `String keys=datas.getKey();`